# iOS jQuery fails to change input value and "addClass" call fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I'm having a problem with jQuery based script when used on iOS (iPhone 6 & 6s). It behaves the same way in Chrome and Safari, but I believe that's because Chrome is actually a wrapper for UIWebView in case of iOS. Anyway, this is a simple "star rating" system. Here is the snippet for it:

```js
;(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.star-rating-input .star', function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var rating = self.data('rating');
        
        self.addClass('selected');
        self.siblings('.star').removeClass('selected');
        self.siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(rating);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
// This is irrelevant here, the only thing to know is that .selected & :focus class makes all previous .star spans change representation using :before pseudo-selector and it works on all other browsers including WP IE.
```

```html
<div class="star-rating-input">
  <span class="star " data-rating="5"></span>
  <span class="star " data-rating="4"></span>
  <span class="star " data-rating="3"></span>
  <span class="star " data-rating="2"></span>
  <span class="star " data-rating="1"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="star_rating" value="">
</div>
```

Normally it works fine, but in both Safari and Chrome on iOS (iPhone 6 and 6s, I can only assume it applies to other versions of iPhone/iOS too):

- The class is not added (so the stars are changing only temporary, until clicked span lose focus)
- The input, despite expecting a string/number value, is populated with HTMLFragment according to Chrome DevTools.

Any idea what may be causing this issue? Perhaps anyone know the solution to that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about this. But I think you're facing the issue because you're trying to detect a click on non-anchor elements (`<span>` in this case). Try adding the following CSS and check it on iOS:

```
.star{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: I simply didn't believe it would work, but tried it anyway and quite a surprise - it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var rating = self.data('rating');
```

Try

```
var rating = self.attr('data-rating');
```

Seeing how functions after this line fail to execute, perhaps the .data is not really supported in iOS. Worth trying out.

EDIT: The .data does work in iOS and, as mentioned, the click event wasn't firing properly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try your solution, because the one marked as correct works, that also means .data() is supported by iOS

Comment: Well, at the time of my posting, your comment under that solution was that it makes no difference, so I assumed you tried it. Hence I assumed that the click event is triggered the .data is sometimes less reliable than the .attr.

Comment: I see, sorry for that, I did delete this comment immediately after I realized I've been testing the old version without that change! Sorry for the confusion. The fact is it works and I also marked your answer as useful, because it lead to conclusion that .data() indeed works on iOS (perhaps you could add that to your answer as an edit, to make it explicit).